# RDFS subclass: property redefinition

Tags: rdf, modeling, rdfs

Toy example:

---

Consider the following types:

- `Hamburger, Veggieburger, Component, Vegetable, Meat`

Where

- `Veggieburger` is `subclass_of` `Hamburger`
- `Vegetable` and `meat` are
  subclasses of `Component`

Consider the following property:

- `Has_component`: domain = `Hamburger`, range = `Component`

---

Now, I want to redefine `Has_component` on the `Veggieburger` and indicate that is can only contain vegetable `Components`.

Is there a way to redefine (i.e. override) the property `Has_component`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only willing to use RDFS, then might I suggest the following:

```
@prefix menu: <http://yourdomain/menu#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.

menu:Burger rdf:type rdfs:Class.

menu:Veggieburger rdf:type rdfs:Class;
                  rdfs:subClassOf menu:Burger.

menu:Hamburger rdf:type rdfs:Class;
               rdfs:subClassOf menu:Burger.

menu:Component rdf:type rdfs:Class.

menu:VeggieComponent rdf:type rdfs:Class;
                     rdfs:subClassOf menu:Component.

menu:MeatComponent rdf:type rdfs:Class;
                   rdfs:subClassOf menu:Component.

#use camel casing for property names
menu:hasComponent rdf:type rdf:Property;
                  rdfs:domain menu:Burger;
                  rdfs:range menu:Component.

menu:hasMeatComponent rdf:type rdf:Property;
                  rdfs:subPropertyOf menu:hasComponent;
                  rdfs:domain menu:MeatBurger;
                  rdfs:range menu:MeatComponent.

menu:hasVeggieComponent rdf:type rdf:Property;
                  rdfs:domain menu:VeggieBurger;
                  rdfs:subPropertyOf menu:hasComponent;
                  rdfs:range menu:VeggieComponent.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another pair domain/range axioms in RDFS, a reasoner will interpret the actual range as the intersection of the two classes, Component & VeggieComponent, which in this instance is ok.  In some cases, that'd be undesirable, so keep that in mind.

You could also do this with OWL & a restriction to get what you want, ala

VeggieBurger subClassOf some(HasComponent, VeggieComponent)

Comment: how would I add a second pair of domain/range axioms?

Comment: William's example illustrates the best way to do this.  Otherwise, you should move onto using OWL if you find what he did insufficient.